# eclipse color plugin not working with PDT/php files

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pdt

I have been using eclipse color plugin for years because i prefer dark background in eclipse instead of white.
but suddenly it seems like eclipse color plugin is not working on php files.after i installed PDT plugin. any solution for this? i am using Obsidian theme on Eclipse Luna.

[image: eclipse color plugin-php file]

Comment: Was it working before? Check the `workspace/.metadata/logs` for logs and ask the devs of the PDT for help.

Comment: I'm using eclipse color plugin with pdt luna and everything is working correctly. You have to change color theme after PDT installation. Can you try: select any other theme, apply settings, switch back to obsidian and apply again. PHP editor should be restarted.

Comment: @rlegendi before i didn't have PDT installed...so php files were getting opened in text editor. it works in text editor but not in php editor.

Comment: @zulus i tried it several times...no luck!

Comment: @zulus nope there are not any logs related to PDT or php editor or eclipse color plugin in workspace/.metadata/logs

Comment: Could you try this? http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/?view=theme&id=24587   or as import eclipse preferences (have to work correctly), or as import to colors

Comment: @zulus i tried that too...no luck though...but on the different machine i freshly installed eclipse and then installed PDT plugin and Eclipse Color theme plugin...it seemed to work perfect...however on my machine it's not working.